# CSS Overflow scroll issue in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, overflow

I have managed to get the content on the reverse side of a "flipbox" to scroll - it works in Firefox but it doesnt work in Chrome. The problem that is happening in Chrome is that instead of the front of the flipbox dispalying, the mirrored image of the reverse side of the flipbox is displayed.

"staffContent" is the div that needs to scroll, the OVERFLOW property is causing the issue.

Thank you for your assistance - I AM A NOVICE!
Cali

/* === CSS ==============================================================*/

```
/* === FLIP BOX =============*/
.card {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 25%;
    padding-bottom: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    min-height: 320px;
    overflow: hidden;
    }


.card__front img{
    position:absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    min-width: 100%;
     }

/* card fronts and backs */
.card__front,
.card__back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}


.card__front,
.card__back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
          transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.card__front {
  background-color: black;
     text-align: center;
    }

.card__back {
  background-color: #89868a;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
          transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}


/* click effect */
.card.effect__click.flipped .card__front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
          transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card.effect__click.flipped .card__back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
          transform: rotateY(0);
}


/* === STAFF PROFILES =============*/

.staff {
    text-align: center;
    }

.staffName h4 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family:'Gibson W01';
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.staffName p {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
}



.staffName {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    z-index: 2000;
    background: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.readMore {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: right;
    bottom: 22px;
    right: 13%;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    z-index: 1000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size:12px;
    background: #cd1719;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    }

.readMore a, a:hover{
    color: white!important;
    }

.staffLinkedIn {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 22px;
    left: 22px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    z-index: 1000;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 28px;
    height: 26px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    }



.staffProfile {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 15px 30px 100px 30px ;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow: scroll;
    }



.staffProfile .entry-content p{
    color: white!important;
}

.staffContent {
padding-bottom: 50px;


}
```

/* === HTML / PHP ======================================================*/

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-centered" > 
                <div class=" staffName gradientHorizontal"><h4><?php the_sub_field('name'); ?></h4><p><?php the_sub_field('title'); ?></p></div>
                    <div class="card effect__click" >
                        <div class="card__front">
                            <?php if( get_sub_field('linked_in') ){ ?>
                                <a class="staffLinkedIn gradientRadial"href="<?php the_sub_field('linked_in'); ?>"  target="_blank" ><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                            <?php } ?>

                            <?php if( $profile_content): ?>
                                    <a class="readMore" href="#/">read more</a>
                            <?php endif; ?>




                            <div class="staffMember ">
                                <img class="align-center"src="<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>" alt="Image of <?php the_sub_field('name'); ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="card__back">
                            <div class="shadow"> </div>
                            <div class="staffProfile gradientVerticleGreySolid">


                                <div class="staffContent">
                                        <h4><?php the_sub_field('name'); ?></h4>
                                        <h5><?php the_sub_field('title'); ?></h5>
                                        <p><?php the_sub_field('profile_content'); ?></p>
                                </div>


                            </div>
                            <div class="closeButton">X</div>
                        </div>
                      </div> <!-- /card -->
            </div> <!-- /col -->
```

/* === JS ===================================================*/

```
// FLIPBOX ON CLICK
(function() {
  var cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card.effect__click");
  for ( var i  = 0, len = cards.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    var card = cards[i];
    clickListener( card );
  }

  function clickListener(card) {
    card.addEventListener( "click", function() {
      var c = this.classList;
      c.contains("flipped") === true ? c.remove("flipped") : c.add("flipped");
    });
  }
})();
```

Comment: I've recreated your project in JSBin and it appears to work fine in both Chrome and Firefox.  The image flips to show a grey background with scrollable text in it: http://jsbin.com/heqisanuva/edit?html,css,js,output - does this look correct to you?

Comment: Thank you Sonya - yes, that is correct. I am not sure what the problem is on my side then. I have been through every bit of code but can't find why it is not working in my browser. I don't think it is something on my computer as I checked it on a different one and it was doing the same thing

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue (Card flip works fine for both FireFox and Safari, not for Chrome when adding scrollbar overflow).  I dug up this discussion and found the solution mentioned worked for me: https://github.com/nnattawat/flip/issues/39

```
.card .front{
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    perspective: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    }
```